# How to run javascript code in XMLHttpRequest before returning response?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I want to list ALL the files in [this shared Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HyDpcxgsYjpGQ4hqw7EqwShsRtPzqYyi?usp=share_link) using **XMLHttpRequest** in **Javascript**.

I can successfully do this using the below snippet:

```
function getSourceAsDOM(url) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    parser = new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "text/html");
}

var googleDriveURL = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HyDpcxgsYjpGQ4hqw7EqwShsRtPzqYyi?usp=share_link';
var googleDriveDOM = getSourceAsDOM(googleDriveURL);
var files = googleDriveDOM.getElementsByClassName("Q5txwe");

console.log(files)
```

The problem is, there's **258** files in there. However, this XMLHttpRequest only returns **50** files *(I'm guessing that's the default display amount in Google Drive)*. When I manually visit the URL, I can only see a few files. Then as I scroll to the bottom of the page, more files are loaded/displayed *(until all files are displayed and I can no longer scroll down)*. I'm wondering how I can have the XMLHttpRequest return the FULL HTML response, so I can get all files.

My initial thought is to run a javascript that scrolls to the bottom of the page a few times *(or until it can't anymore)*, before returning the XMLHttpRequest response. That way, the full HTML is loaded, and I can then get all my files from that DOM. But I'm open to any other way, as long as it yields all of the files.

**P.S:** I do NOT want to use GoogleDriveAPI.

I'm new to Javascript/HTML, so apologies if this is a trivial question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no easy way to run the JS to get the dynamic changes to the DOM. If you do this in Python you could use Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser.

Comment: "*run a javascript that scrolls to the bottom of the page a few times before returning the XMLHttpRequest response. That way, the full HTML is loaded, and I can then get all my files from that DOM.*" - that's not how `XMLHttpRequest` works. It loads an XML document, it does not open it as a webpage. It neither executes javascript nor renders the html into anything that is scrollable

Comment: "*I do NOT want to use GoogleDriveAPI.*" - why not? You really should!

Comment: I think that in your situation when the folder is publicly shared, the file list can be retrieved by Google Drive API with an API key. In this case, it is not required to use the access token. So, I think that your goal can be achieved with a simple script. But, from `P.S: I do NOT want to use GoogleDriveAPI.`, if you don't want to use Drive API even when your goal can be achieved by an API key, I apologize for my proposal.

Comment: @Bergi I am under the impression that GoogleDriveAPI only allows the user to access Google Drive information from whichever Gmail account it's logged into. But it doesn't take a public Google Drive folder URL, and obtain file info from there. But please correct me if I'm wrong, in which case, I will use the GoogleDriveAPI. Thanks!

Comment: @Tanaike I'm going to try to setup GoogleDriveAPI. Maybe I misunderstood how it works. I just couldn't see any information in the docs on how to fetch info from a public 
 Google Drive URL. If you have any resources on this specific topic I would love to take a look at them. Thank you!

Comment: @Bergi Also the reason I'm hesitant to use GoogleDriveAPI, is that it requires the user to have a Gmail account with Google Drive enabled. But I can't guarantee that every user will meet that requirement. So that's why I was opting for XMLHttpRequest. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: When you use Drive API and the folder is publicly shared, please create your API key. [Ref](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862) And, using your API key, please modify your current endpoint to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=%271HyDpcxgsYjpGQ4hqw7EqwShsRtPzqYyi%27%20in%20parents&key={your API key}` using ["Files: list" method of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). By this, the file list can be obtained. From your question, 258 files can be obtained by one API call. If my comments were not useful, I apologize.